# io.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit() - has no method 'socket'

Tags: node.js, socket.io-1.0

im running a nodejs server + express + socket.io version 1.0.4 and everything works as expected in my app, but i just cant emit a message from server side to client side via:

```
socket_server.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit("message", data);
```

when i try server throws following error:

```
    TypeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method 'socket'
```

but i can remember that code worked on my socket.io 0.7.*/0.8.* projects

What am i doing wrong? :(

a snippet out of my app.js (nodejs server):

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/* Server Start */
var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});

app.set("view options", {
    layout: false
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

var socket_server = require('socket.io').listen(server);
socket_server.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
// fire my emits here like: socket_server.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit("msg", data);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using socket_server.sockets.socket(socket_id) instead of the way given in demo. If this is the code for old version, it maynot work with 1.0. Try refractoring your code for newer version.

Comment: which way is given in demo for emitting to one specific socket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1.0 you should use:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit();
```

to emit to a specific client.

```
socket_server.sockets.socket(socket_id).emit();
```

has been replaced in socket.io 1.0.

Answer (score 5):

In version >= 1.0 you should use:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit();
```

where socket.id is the id as string. The solution was found by victorwoo in following thread https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1618

Note: The solution describe above by Tony Chen

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit();
```

didn't worked for me, since io.sockets.connected is an array of socket objects and not string (id)

Answer (score 0):

Change your last part of code to:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('msg',data);
    //to only that client
    io.sockets.emit('msg',data);
    //to all sockets.
}
```

`io` is your `socket_server`. And you listen for connections to it, not to its sockets.

Answer (score 0):

in 1.x version, u can find in docs a list of migration tips from oldest version, especifically

> Broadcasting to all clients in default namespace
>
> Previously:
>
> io.sockets.emit('eventname', 'eventdata');
>
> Now:
>
> io.emit('eventname', 'eventdata');

red the docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#)