# Object #<Namespace> has no method 'socket'

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am new to node.js i want to emit socket to specific socket id but i am getting `Object #<Namespace> has no method 'socket'` error. Here is my code:-

```
 var io = socketio.listen(app)
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("user-typing", function (data) {
       io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('user-typing-start', "End Typing");//i am getting error here
    })
 });
```

I am using socket.io v1.0.
i have already try this answer but not working:- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221820/io-sockets-socketsocket-id-emit-has-no-method-socket)

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: @BenFortune i am getting `connected is not a function` error if i use that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have provided does not work with Socket.IO 1.0

Instead you may try this solution:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('user-typing-start', "End Typing");
```

or (if you have access to `socket` object like in your example):

```
socket.emit('user-typing-start', "End Typing");
```