# Socket.io error sending message to socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

There is a code line:

```
io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('counter', { all : data.all, dialog : data.dialog });
```

It gives me exception:

```
TypeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method 'socket'
```

My **connection** event:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {});
```

Why object **socket** is no?

**Full code:**

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8181, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port "+ app.get('port') +" in "+ app.get('env') +" mode.");
});

var io = socketio.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket server creation for use with express. Look at http://socket.io/docs/ for more information and help.

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(8181);

io.on('connect', function(socket) {
    socket.on('example', function(data) {
        //parse the data, do something, create response data object, etc.

    });
});
```

And with HTTP + Express

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8181);

io.on('connect', function(socket) {
        socket.on('example', function(data) {
            //parse the data, do something, create response data object, etc.

        });
    });
```

For the emit you are trying to create (my below example will broadcast only to the connected socket, by providing the .to(socket.id) )

```
io.to(socket.id).emit('counter', {all : data.all, dialog : data.dialog});
```

Comment: i tried your example witout `io.sockets` - the error is same

Comment: Do you have io pulled into your server? `var io = require('socket.io');` This would be within your server.js file.

Comment: Yes, in a top script there is: `socketio = require('socket.io');` `var io = socketio.listen(server);`

Comment: Ok, this may seem like a trivial fix, but humor me. Looking at the latest socket server we wrote, I have the following setup code: `var io = require('socket.io');` and `var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(port);  // remember thy port
require('./config/sockets').start(io.listen(server));`  You can use just io.listen(server) with this code (we have our socket code abstracted into config/sockets).

Comment: I think you were missing a couple of things in your full code there, such as the express require. Look at my full code example above, and then I strongly suggest the socket.io docs link I have provided.

Comment: So, your code is running, but error is too at: `io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit` (:

Comment: Coool...problem is resolved. This answers helped me. I use socket.io version 1.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221820/io-sockets-socketsocket-id-emit-has-no-method-socket

Comment: I could make an argument for why my solution is more elegant :). "Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id." So you can just emit to the socket.id (as I provided in my answer above!). Cheers for working!